# how to check if the data types of field are changed in sqlite db

Tags: android, android-sqlite

First I created a data base table in `Android SQLite DB` like :

```
private static final String CONTENT_DB_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + CONTENT_DB_NAME + "( " + CONTENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
        CONTENT_TITLE   + " TEXT, " +
        CONTENT_FULLTEXT    + " TEXT , " +
        CONTENT_STATE   + " TEXT , " +
        CONTENT_NEW + " TEXT, " +
        CONTENT_HEADER  + " TEXT , " +
        CONTENT_COLOR   + " TEXT , " +
        CONTENT_NEXT    + " TEXT , " +
        CONTENT_PREVIOUS + " TEXT );";
```

Then I changed to this :

```
private static final String CONTENT_DB_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + CONTENT_DB_NAME + "( " + CONTENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
        CONTENT_TITLE   + " TEXT, " +
        CONTENT_FULLTEXT    + " TEXT , " +
        CONTENT_STATE   + " INTEGER , " +
        CONTENT_NEW + " INTEGER, " +
        CONTENT_HEADER  + " TEXT , " +
        CONTENT_COLOR   + " INTEGER , " +
        CONTENT_NEXT    + " TEXT , " +
        CONTENT_PREVIOUS + " TEXT );";
```

Now How Can I be sure that the data types are changed!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use this query to fetch the current SQL statement that defines your table:

```
"SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master " +
    " WHERE type = 'table' AND tbl_name = '" + CONTENT_DB_NAME + "'"
```

`sqlite_master` is a hidden table that holds your entire database's schema.

Understand that the column type might not matter since SQLite uses ["type affinity"](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity).

Answer (score 0):

There are some utilities to view your data base.
You can get the data base using file explorer
The database for a specific app lives in /data/data/[packagename]/databases

The packagename is the package you define in your manifest, for instance /data/data/org.vimtips.supacount/databases/counts.db.

You can view it with adb shell and type sqlite3 /data/data/org.vimtips.supacount/databases/counts.db

Or you can pull it from the device to look at it with a third party utility, with a command like adb pull /data/data/org.vimtips.supacount/databases/counts.db